# jQuery form validation with PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I'm working on a form validation with PHP variables, just to not repeat myself in HTML when it comes to displaying default values of text inputs & textareas. Basically, what I want to achieve, is that **each field has it's own default value, which disappears on focus and appears back on blur**, if user hasn't typed anything in.

Then it validates, if user hasn't left fields with default values (which would make default values red, to bring users focus to them). After submitting, form slides up and shows div#thanks with button allowing to show the form again, with text area cleared.

Validation is working ok without PHP variables (there is also server side validation, in case of switched off JS).

PS. Also form appears after clicking on a#opt4, but that part works fine, too.

PS2. My head is melted at this stage, so wouldn't be surprised if there is some ridiculous bugs, just to warn you

```
$(document).ready(function() {

<!--
<?php

    $defaultMsg = "Please type in your message";
    $defaultEmail = "Your Email";
    $defaultName = "Your name (optional)";

?>
-->

$('#contact-form').hide();

$('a#opt4').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#contact-form').slideToggle("normal", function() {

        if ( $(".mobile-sp").css("display") === "none") {

            $('html, body').toggleState(function (el) {
                el.animate({
                scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top
            }, 800);
            }, function (el) {

            });

        }

    });

    $('textarea, input[type="text"]').focus(function() {

        if ( $(this).hasClass('error')) {

            $(this).removeClass('error');

        }

        var text = $(this).val();

        $(this).animate({
            color: "#fff"
        },400, function () {

            if ((text === <?php echo $defaultMsg; ?>) || (text === <?php echo defaultEmail; ?>)) {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });
    });
    $('textarea, input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            color: "#6599cb"
        },400, function () {
            if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
                $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

// validation

```
$("#thanks").hide();
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#submit").click(function(){

    $(".error").hide();
    $("#one-more").hide();

    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var emailFromVal = $("#emailFrom").val();
    var defaultEmail = <?php echo $defaultEmail; ?>;

    if((emailFromVal == '') || (emailFromVal === defaultEmail)) {
        $("#email").val('defaultEmail');
        hasError = true;
    } else if(!emailReg.test(emailFromVal)) {
        $("#email").val('defaultEmail');
        hasError = true;
    }

    var messageVal = $("#message").val();
    var defaultMsg = <?php echo $defaultMsg; ?>;

    if((messageVal == '') || (messageVal === defaultMsg)) {
        $("textarea").val('#message'.defaultValue).addClass('error');
        hasError = true;
    }


    if(hasError == false) {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#sendEmail button").append('<img src="modules/contact/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" />');

        $.post("modules/contact/sendEmail.php",
            { emailFrom: emailFromVal, message: messageVal },
                function(data){
                    $("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {

                        $("#thanks").slideDown("normal", function() {
                            $("#one-more").slideDown("slow");
                        });

                    });
                }
             );
    }

    return false;
});
```

```
$("#one-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var defaultMsg = <?php echo $defaultMsg; ?>;

    $('#thanks').slideUp("slow",function() {
        $('form').slideDown('slow', function() {
            $('#submit').show();
            $('#message').val('defaultMsg');
        });
    });
});
```

});

// HTML

```
<div id="form">

            <?php include('modules/contact/verify.php'); ?>

            <h2>Talk to us about your project</h2>

            <form action="" method="post" id="sendEmail">

                <textarea name="message" id="message"><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])) { echo $_POST['message']; } else { echo $defaultMsg; } ?></textarea><?php if(isset($messageError)) echo '<span class="error">'.$messageError.'</span>'; ?>

                <input type="text" name="emailFrom" id="emailFrom"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['emailFrom'])) { echo $_POST['emailFrom']; } else { echo $defaultEmail; } ?>"><?php if(isset($emailFromError)) echo '<span class="error">'.$emailFromError.'</span>'; ?>

                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $defaultName; ?>">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true">

            </form>

            <div id="thanks">

                <div class="container">

                    <img src="gfx/sprites/icn-contact-success.png">
                    <h3>Thank you.</h3>
                    <p>We will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>

                </div>

                    <a href="#" class="btn" id="one-more">Oh no, wait! I want to add something!</a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: i hope you validate server side to, as js can be disabled

Comment: yup, like i mentioned, thx

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the "placeholder" attribute?

Comment: good question mate, hmmm yeah I guess I should